# Flip Flop numbers check

Tags: java

The output numbers are displayed from 1 to `max`, one per line with the following exceptions:

- numbers divisible by `a` are replaced with the word *"Flip"*
- the numbers divisible by `b` are replaced with the word *"Flop"*
- numbers divisible by both are replaced by *"FlipFlop"*

I am stuck and need a little direction to where my problem is. I thought maybe a `for` loop would be perfect to go through and list the numbers and have the `if else` to check each number with the input numbers picked by the user.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class FlipFlop {
    public static void FlipFlop(Integer a, Integer b, Integer Max) {
        for (int i = 1; i < Max; i++) {
            if (i % a == 0) {
                System.out.println("Flip");
            } else if (i % b == 0) {
                System.out.println("Flop");
            } else if (i % a == 0 && i % b == 0) {
                System.out.println("FlipFlop");
            } else {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        Integer a;
        Integer b;
        Integer max;
        String Title = "FlipFlop Assignment";
        String data = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your first number", Title, 1);
        a = new Integer(data);
        data = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your second number", Title, 1);
        b = new Integer(data);
        data = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the upper bound", Title, 1);
        max = new Integer(data);
        FlipFlop(a, b, max);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] to add a specific problem statement — "it doesn't work" can be assumed, but *how* does it not work? What error message or incorrect behavior is characteristic?

Comment: Ditto. What error are you getting?

Comment: Sorry! It cant find the symbol for "max" integer in the for loop. The max symbol is an integer being inputted by the user.

Comment: since you start by testing `a` individually, you can never reach the case where `a` and `b` are valid.

Comment: (just put your test on a and b first)

Comment: I recognize this assignment from some coding challenge, maybe Project Euler or BAPC. StackOverflow doesn't exist to do people's homework.

Answer (score 0):

- `Integer`, not `integer`. That makes `max` undefined in the first function. Also look into `int`.
- You never actually assign anything to `max`
- All those `println` functions, you never defined `Flip`, `Flop` and `FlipFlop`. Presumably they're either missing string constants or just plain string literals. (actually your case is even worse, `FlipFlop` is your function so you're passing the function reference which I bet confuses Java even more)
- The flipflop case should come before the other two. Pen and paper should trivially explain why.

Comment: My mistake on the println statements. I just want it to check if the number is divisible by a and b to print out flip or flop. I am getting an error saying "FlipFlop.java:29: error: unexpected type
   }else if(i % a = 0 && i % b = 0){
              ^

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here, but the overall code is very close to what you want.

`integer max;` is creating a variable using an unreal type, I believe you want to be using the passed in variable `Max` which has a capital 'M'.  Be careful of case sensitivity with variables.  Generally non-final variables should start with a lower-case letter to prevent confusion.

If you delete the `integer max` and change your method's `Max` to `max` it solves some of your trouble, because right now you aren't using the passed in `Max` value at all.  Unless you yourself have created a class named "integer" you cannot create variables using it.

You are not checking equality in your if statements, you are trying to assign a value.  The '=' is trying to assign a value, you want '==' which checks for value equality.

You should move the if statement checking for both Flip and Flop first, because as it is if both are true, only "Flip" will print.

Last, nothing will print at all right now because you don't have Flip, Flop, or FlipFlop inside quotes.  You will get a compiler error because there is no variable or class named Flip, or Flop.  `System.out.println("Flip");` is what you want.